# linux/init.h not in usr/include/linux directroy

Tags: linux, driver

When trying to include `linux/init.h` my editor tells me that this file does not exist. did some researching on how to fix this I found `/usr/src` that has some ,I assume kernel version, when I [looked up on how to install header files for linux drivers development](https://www.tecmint.com/install-kernel-headers-in-ubuntu-and-debian/). what I did was i moved a bunch of folder in `linux-headers-5.10.0-kali4-common` into `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib/module/5.10.0-kali4-amd64/source`.

For a time I thought it worked but gave me a new error `cannot open source file "asm/rwonce.h" (dependency of "linux/init.h")` and `cannot open source file "asm/linkage.h" (dependency of "linux/module.h")`.At this point I got frustrated. turned off everything and now I am here.

Now I want know is there a better method to getting the source and dependencies I need for linux driver development.so far google was not very helpful. and I am tired of moving files around that may or may not damage my system.

Answer (score 0):

First undo what you did.

Then, install the kernel source.  In the root directory is the README file which describes requirements for building drivers and points you to the detailed documentation contained in the source tree. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/README